# strange behavior of regex (?:)

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting

in the following relative url I want to get the optional origin parameter but I just need the origin itself (that would be **test** in the following url not **with-test-origin**)

```
/somequery/with-test-origin/param/param/more
```

the url matches when I use this regular expression:

```
([^/]+)/(?:(?:with-)([^/]*)(-origin)/)?([^/]*/)?([^/]*/)?more
```

but not when I use this:

```
([^/]+)/(?:(?:with-)([^/]*)(?:-origin)/)?([^/]*/)?([^/]*/)?more
```

what is the problem? why it doesn't work when I don't want to catch **(-origin)** group?

**Edit:**

I test it in an application it worked fine. I also tried this in web.config:

```
([^/]+)/(?:(with-)([^/]*)(?:-origin)/)?([^/]*/)?([^/]*/)?more
```

in web.config (removed ?: from **(?:with-)** and put it back in (?:-origin) and it worked in web.config too. Is there a limitation in web.config file for the amount of groups or the groups I don't want to catch?

this is how I use it in my web.config file:

```
<rule name="tst" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([^/]+)/(?:(?:with-)([^/]*)(?:-origin)/)?([^/]*/)?([^/]*/)?more" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="moreinfo.aspx?cat={R:1}&amp;sub1={R:2}&amp;sub2={R:3}&amp;sub3={R:4}&amp;sub4={R:5}" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/xW8kZ0/2 it's working.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm using it in the web.config file for url rewriting it doesn't work there

Comment: What's the error messages? It throws exception, says there is no matches?

Comment: i think you need to turn all the capturing groups to non-capturing group other than the one which holds test https://regex101.com/r/xW8kZ0/3

Comment: @George well when I omit ?: from (?:-origin) it rewrites the url but otherwise it shows the common error page that always show when a url doesn't match

Comment: @AvinashRaj but I need the other groups too I just don't need some of them

Comment: If you can please test it in web.config

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani now I can only give you common advice. Try this regex separately, try to debug it by removing its parts. Also check out if `(?:-` has no special meaning.

Comment: @George I actually removed the dash to make sure if it has a special meaning but it didn't change anything

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani well, then test it separately with your regex engine to ensure that error is in regex itself.

Comment: @George what do you mean by **separately**

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani you put your regex in config file. Also you can create simple app that parses string using your regex.

Comment: @George I checked it in application and it works fine but when I put it in web.config file it doesn't. what is the limitation in web.config?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani also check it out to which capturing groups you refer later

Comment: Please complete your question and show how you refer to the captured groups.

Comment: I finally found the answer. It was my mistake but a tricky one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggles I found the problem at last.

the matches are zero based and are like {R:0} {R:1} , ...
When using **?:** as the number of matches were reduced by 1 so for example the {R:1} that were valid before adding **?:** turns to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The matching behavior *should not* change based on this difference.  The problem is either:

- Something else in your web.config file.
- A bug in the regex engine or web.config.

Comment: As I have cleared all web.config then the first one is not the case and in my web page I tested it with Regex.Match it worked too so I don't think bug in regex engine would be the case either. I'm looking too see if there is a limitation for regex in web.config. I solved my problem fetching all groups but ignoring those I don't need but I'm really curious what the problem is here